# Change currency according to geo/locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a rails app. I would like to show prices on my products based on where the user is from. Is there are rails gem which will auto convert currency depending on the system's locale or possibly geo?

Answer (score 0):

Use the helpers that Rails provides. Example:

```
number_to_currency(300, locale: :fr) # Will display 300€
```

The default locale is the current locale, so you just could do

```
number_to_currency(300)
```

Comment: This is not working. My current locale is set to en_GB but it still showing the number_to_currency value in USD.

Comment: Add the following file to your locales https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml